# PriorityQueue not working properly

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have made a priority queue which inserts objects and compares them with cost parameter, when two costs are equal it should keep them in enqueued order, but I found after debugging one time it is in enqueued order and other time it is not in the order but I am not getting what is wrong with my code I couldn't find any other post helping.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Node implements Comparable<Node>
{
    int x, y, dir;

    Node(int x, int y, int dir)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node o)
    {
        if (Ideone.cost[o.x][o.y] == Ideone.cost[x][y]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            int d = Ideone.cost[x][y] - Ideone.cost[o.x][o.y];
            if (d > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Ideone
{
    public static int[][] cost;
    static PriorityQueue<Node> p;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        p = new PriorityQueue<Node>();

        cost = new int[13][11];

        for (int[] row : cost)
            Arrays.fill(row, -1);

        cost[0][8]  = 366564;
        cost[2][9]  = 368282;
        cost[1][3]  = 368282;
        cost[4][9]  = 368282;
        cost[0][9]  = 376564;
        cost[1][9]  = 372423;
        cost[5][9]  = 372423;
        cost[0][3]  = 436564;
        cost[7][0]  = 378282;
        cost[2][10] = 378282;
        cost[4][10] = 378282;
        cost[0][4]  = 382423;
        p.add(new Node(0, 8, 8));
        p.add(new Node(2, 9, 8));
        p.add(new Node(1, 3, 7));
        p.add(new Node(4, 9, 2));
        p.add(new Node(0, 9, 8));
        p.add(new Node(1, 9, 8));
        p.add(new Node(5, 9, 2));
        p.add(new Node(0, 3, 6));
        p.add(new Node(7, 0, 3));
        p.add(new Node(2, 10, 8));
        p.add(new Node(4, 10, 2));
        p.add(new Node(0, 4, 7));

        while (p.size() != 0) {
            Node n1 = p.poll();
            System.out.println(n1.x + " " + n1.y + " " + cost[n1.x][n1.y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
0 8 366564
1 3 368282
2 9 368282
4 9 368282
5 9 372423
1 9 372423
0 9 376564
4 10 378282
2 10 378282
7 0 378282
0 4 382423
0 3 436564
```

but I am expecting:

```
0 8 366564
2 9 368282
1 3 368282
4 9 368282
1 9 372423
5 9 372423
0 9 376564
7 0 378282
2 10 378282
4 10 378282
0 4 382423
0 3 436564
```

Comment: See the API for [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) - to quote: `ties are broken arbitrarily.`

Comment: but i am returning 1 to specify that newly inserted value is greater than previous and place it in end

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne You can add the insertion order as an additional field so this information is not lost.

Comment: and i am doing this queue in large code where many insertions take place storing them and searching for equality is not a better idea but what is my mistake i am not at all letting to know that two elements are equal for breaking ties i am implementing compareto in that way

Comment: “but i am returning 1 to specify that newly inserted value is greater than previous”: sorry, it does not work this way. The priority queue may call newNode.compareTo(existingNode) or existingNode.compareTo(newNode) to determine their order. When either call returns 1 and you don’t know which one it takes, you also don’t know which order they get.

Comment: `but i am returning 1 to specify that newly inserted value is greater than previous and place it in end` And therein lies the problem. A PriorityQueue uses a binary heap (aka Tree) to order its elements - there is no guarantee that the compareTo method will be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need — as in need — to follow the suggestion from Peter Lawrey and store the insertion order in each Node you insert into the priority queue. It’s easier to explain in code. Your node class could become:

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node>
{
    int x, y, dir;
    /** the order in which the node was inserted into the priority queue (if it was) */
    int insertionOrder;

    Node(int x, int y, int dir, int insertionOrder)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dir = dir;
        this.insertionOrder = insertionOrder;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node o)
    {
        int d = Ideone.cost[x][y] - Ideone.cost[o.x][o.y];
        if (d == 0) {
            // keep insertion order
            return insertionOrder - o.insertionOrder;
        } else {
            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

And your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    p = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
    int numInserted = 0;

    cost = new int[13][11];

    for (int[] row : cost)
        Arrays.fill(row, -1);

    cost[0][8]  = 366564;
    cost[2][9]  = 368282;
    cost[1][3]  = 368282;
    cost[4][9]  = 368282;
    cost[0][9]  = 376564;
    cost[1][9]  = 372423;
    cost[5][9]  = 372423;
    cost[0][3]  = 436564;
    cost[7][0]  = 378282;
    cost[2][10] = 378282;
    cost[4][10] = 378282;
    cost[0][4]  = 382423;
    p.add(new Node(0, 8, 8, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(2, 9, 8, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(1, 3, 7, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(4, 9, 2, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(0, 9, 8, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(1, 9, 8, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(5, 9, 2, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(0, 3, 6, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(7, 0, 3, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(2, 10, 8, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(4, 10, 2, numInserted));
    numInserted++;
    p.add(new Node(0, 4, 7, numInserted));
    numInserted++;

    while (p.size() != 0) {
        Node n1 = p.poll();
        System.out.println(n1.x + " " + n1.y + " " + cost[n1.x][n1.y]);
    }
}
```

The above main method prints:

```
0 8 366564
2 9 368282
1 3 368282
4 9 368282
1 9 372423
5 9 372423
0 9 376564
7 0 378282
2 10 378282
4 10 378282
0 4 382423
0 3 436564
```

I believe this was what you expected.

Comment: If more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` insertions may happen during the lifetime of the queue, you will need to use a `long` for the insertion order. That is, about 2 billion (2 thousand million).

Comment: In a large system, you may want to build a subclass of `PriorityQueue` that handles the assignment of insertion order for you as the nodes are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

A [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) uses a [BinaryHeap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) to order it's elements. This means there is no guarantee each element will be compared to the others upon insertion (and thus the order of addition for equal elements retained). In order to retain the order of addition for equal elements, you need to have another comparison between the elements. One possible way could be to use a timestamp for each node

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node>
{
    int x, y, dir;
    Long timestamp = System.nanoTime();

    Node(int x, int y, int dir)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node o){

        if (Ideone.cost[o.x][o.y] == Ideone.cost[x][y]) {
            return timestamp.compareTo(o.timestamp);
        }else {
            int d = Ideone.cost[x][y] - Ideone.cost[o.x][o.y];
            if (d > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

This has drawbacks if multi-threading is involved, in which case you will need to store the order of addition and use that value to compare

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node>
{
    int x, y, dir, pos;

    Node(int x, int y, int dir, int pos)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dir = dir;
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node o){

        if (Ideone.cost[o.x][o.y] == Ideone.cost[x][y]) {
            Integer p1 = pos;
            return p1.compareTo(o.pos);
        }else {
            int d = Ideone.cost[x][y] - Ideone.cost[o.x][o.y];
            if (d > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }  
}

//then to add
p.add(new Node(0, 8, 8, p.size()));
```

Of course, the latter method has drawbacks if removal and addition of items are interleaved (in which case you will need a separate variable to keep an increment of insertions)

```
int additionValue = 0;
p.add(new Node(0, 8, 8, additionValue++));
```

Comment: you and I are thinking rather much along the same lines. If the nodes are inserted in the same order they are created, the timestamp is a rather elegant solution. If not, one of the other methods should be chosen. Since this is not a `PriorityBlockingQueue`, I hope no multithreading is involved.